# Handling send email error on Laravel 5

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, send

I am trying to send email confirmation to user on local but I got this error.

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "521",
with message "521 5.2.1 MUST COMPLETE IMAGE PUZZLE BEFORE SENDING.
PLEASE GOTO http://challenge.aol.com/spam.html
```

How can i catch this error like that to a messenger and return for client.
please give some sugestion.  Thank

Comment: I think you are using **aol mail** to send email. I think you have aol mail **authentication problem**. **`Is your mail configuration are correct?`**

Comment: i know that problem from out side API AOL mail. but i want to cacth it from laravel and return for client a true or false value when email send fail not that messenger. Thank for your comment.